# Right way to "reserve or shrink" a vector to a known future capacity need

Tags: c++, stdvector

I've written countless software modules around the common theme of a long lived vector that some times (at unspecified frequency) must have its content updated.

Idiomatic implementation:

```
void LongLived::reconfigure(const InputT& whatever_input)
{
    m_vector.clear();

    m_vector.reserve(whatever_input.size());

    populate(m_vector, whatever_input);
}
```

Notice that the idiomatic implementation will *never* reduce the capacity of its internal buffer. What if this is not ok? Just use `shrink_to_fit()`, I thought:

```
void LongLived::reconfigure(const InputT& whatever_input)
{
    m_vector.clear();

    m_vector.reserve(whatever_input.size());
    m_vector.shrink_to_fit(whatever_input.size()); // ← Here

    populate(m_vector, whatever_input);
}
```

Oh, how nice that would be… But to my surprise, it doesn't compile, because `shrink_to_fit()` doesn't take a number!

The way `shrink_to_fit()` is supposed to be used, apparently, is that you fill the vector first. Then, you call `shrink_to_fit()`, which is going to derive the capacity need from the number of elements in the vector after the fact, but that is clearly suboptimal if I could have told it that beforehand, because now, all that content has to be moved.

Objective: I would like a function `vector_reserve_or_shrink()` to be used in this context:

```
void LongLived::reconfigure(const InputT& whatever_input)
{
    m_vector.clear();

    vector_reserve_or_shrink(m_vector, whatever_input.size()); // ← Implement this!

    populate(m_vector, whatever_input);
}
```

I'm not actually obsessed with shaving every unused byte off the vector. Rather, I would be glad to leave it up to something implementation defined like `shrink_to_fit()`, which might know something about the quirks of the allocator, and may choose to do nothing. This way, one doesn't risk making an [abstraction inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_inversion) that negates any lower level optimizations. For example, say the allocator's granularity is 16: Then, the vector implementation might like to give you 15 bytes for free when you ask for one, for all I know, which would just be counterproductive to try to give back.

Comment: The contents will **always** have to be copied/moved if `shrink_to_fit()` resizes the memory (because of reallocation), so nothing would be lost by calling `shrink_to_fit()` after populating.

Comment: I would think reserve and shrink_to_fit would be pretty much orthogonal. reserve ensures a certain capacity (used or not) while shrink_to_fit deals only with elements that actually exist in the vector.

Comment: It looks like the *only* way to know what size the vector will be on `shrink_to_fit` is to call it when the vector has the appropriate number of elements, which will definitely call the copy/move constructor that many times if it does any reallocation. If you want to potentially shrink without calling the copy/move constructor, you need to call `shrink_to_fit` with no elements, which will shrink too small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
template <typename VECTOR>
void setCapacity(VECTOR &vector, std::size_t capacity) {
    if (capacity < vector.size()) capacity = vector.size();
    if (vector.capacity() > capacity) {
        VECTOR v;
        v.reserve(capacity);
        std::size_t size = vector.size();
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            v.emplace_back(std::move(vector[i]));
        }
        vector.swap(v);
    } else {
        vector.reserve(capacity);
    }
}
```

It sets vector capacity to `capacity` (if possible), while retaining elements. And it only does one allocation.

Comment: Why not just shrink to fit the vector, why use v?

Comment: @Yakk: this is the only way (if you know the element count of populate), if you want to have **only one** allocation & elements-move, and you want to do this capacity change **before** populate. Check out, for example, Galik's answer. That solution does two allocations. Actually, this function is quite useful, it should be in the vector API already.

Comment: resize zero, shrink to fit, reserve?

Comment: That will remove elements which already in the vector. For the OP, it works, but in the general case, people don't expect it.

Comment: What do you think `vector.swap(v)`, followed by destroying `v`, does to the elements in `vector`?

Comment: @Yakk: do you see a potential problem? As I see, `vector` should not be affected by that.

Comment: @veza `v1.swap(v2)` followed by clearing `v2` deallocates the contents of `v1` and replaces it with the contents of `v2`.

Comment: @Yakk: please be a little bit less cryptic, and tell what's the problem, if there any.

Comment: In short, your use of `v` is pointless in your code?  When I asked you why `v` exists, and pointed out an alternative, you claimed it was for reasons that where not true.  I pointed out that your reasons where wrong, and you ... asked me to be less cryptic.  I am uncertain how to be less cryptic or describe the problem clearer.

Comment: @Yakk, please. I really don't know what's the problem. You first asked a question "What do you think...", which is a question, not a problem description. I can only guess what you mean. Then you said the `v1.swap(v2)` thing, which I don't follow, because I have `vector` and `v`. What is the problem? An empty `vector` will be returned? Or a vector with bad capacity? Or what? I create `v`, with `capacity` capacity, and elements from `vector`. Then I swap `v` with `vector`, so `vector` will have the same elements as it had at entry, but with `capacity` capacity...

Comment: @Yakk ... then `v` is destroyed at return. Where is the problem? Is there anything which doesn't happen as I described? (It could be, I'm not a STL guru, I don't use it - I have my own containers, so it is possible that something doesn't work as I presumed)

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class V>
void hard_reserve( V& v, std::size_t capacity ){
  if (v.capacity() > capacity) v.shrink_to_fit();
  v.reserve(capacity);
}
```

it isn't perfect in some corner cases, but those will be corner cases of an already corner case, and `std` does not provide containers suitable for the many angled one.

Comment: This doesn’t work well when `v.size()` is much less than `capacity()`, as is the case here when the vector is cleared first.

Comment: @daniel how so?  If capacity is larger than target, this code will deallocate everything then reserve up to target capacity.

Comment: if capacity is just the right size for target, this does extra deallocation and allocation that aren't necessary.

Comment: @danielh No, if `capacity()` is equal to target `capacity`, zero deallocations and allocations are done.  I do not understand what you think my code does, but I believe you misunderstand it.  Please test and/or clarify by actually explaining why you think your claims are true.

Comment: The question called `clear` first. In that case, if the vector had had `n` elements and the new needed size was `n - 1`, the `shrink_to_fit` would reduce the capacity (because the vector had been cleared) and the `reserve` would re-increase it. That is wasteful.

Comment: @DanielH Yes, it does: it attempts to force capacity to exactly the argument in question.  If you want a fudge factor, it is easy to add in.

Comment: No, it doesn’t, which is why `v.capacity()` might be greater than `capacity`, and thus `shrink_to_fit()` might be called. In that case it would shrink to fit zero elements, and the reserve would re-grow the vector, which is wasteful if the old vector was the right size.

Answer (score 1):

`shrink_to_fit` may - but is not obliged to - reduce the capacity of the vector to it's `size`. So if you are looking for method that reduces a vectors capacity in an "optimal" manner, `shrink_to_fit` might be the right choice.

Of course, `shrink_to_fit` does not take a parameter, since the vector's size is taken as reference. So the only thing you need to do is to `clear`, then `reserve`, populate in order to fill up the the desired size, and *finally* `shrink_to_fit`:

```
void LongLived::reconfigure(const InputT& whatever_input)
{
    m_vector.clear();
    m_vector.reserve(whatever_input.size());
    populate(m_vector, whatever_input);
    m_vector.shrink_to_fit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void LongLived::reconfigure(const InputT& whatever_input)
{
    m_vector.clear();
    m_vector.shrink_to_fit();
    m_vector.reserve(whatever_input.size());
    populate(m_vector, whatever_input);
}
```

`shrink_to_fit` on an empty vector works quite good on all implementations as far as i know. It doesn't lead to a new memory allocation. The only allocation will be done by `reserve`.

No elements `T`will be copied and it avoids the memory peak of keeping two blocks of memory due to reallocation.

Instead of using `shrink_to_fit` to free the memory it is also possible to clear the vector by swap in an extra function (or scope). This also avoids the memory peak of holding two buffers.

```
void free_vector(std::vector<T> & vec, std::size_t new_size)
{
    std::vector<T> new_vec;
    vec.swap(new_vec);
}
```

Comment: You fail to use new size in your function.